# Reference request: algebraic characteristic 0 version of microlocalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, micro-local-analysis, constructible-sheaves

I am trying to learn about microlocalization and singular supports with the end goal of understanding at least some form of the coherent-constructible correspondence. I am currently powering through Kashiwara and Schapira's "Sheaves on Manifolds", but honestly, I have never felt more like I am reading math line by line without getting even a glimpse of the general picture.

The [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/microlocalization) on microlocalization states

> The original construction is based on the use of the specialization functor and Fourier-Sato transformation. In this section, we will discuss the construction in a general setting, i.e., over an arbitrary field of characteristic
> 0
> . In the real situation, one usually refines the construction by using conic sheaves (i.e., sheaves invariant with respect to the natural $\mathbb{R}^+$-action) to get information about the oriented direction of propagation of singularities of sheaves of solutions of analytic partial differential systems. The construction we describe does not treat this refined information.

Does anyone perhaps know a reference for this less specific version of specialization and Fourier-Sato transformation? I am a more algebraically minded person, and I feel like it would be really helpful for me to first get familiar with the algebraic construction and then refine it to the real situation.

Comment: These notes from a course by Nadler were really nice for me : https://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/ (look at "microlocal geometry". I hope it helps.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks! I did not yet get to microlocalization in these notes, but the first few lectures were already helpful.